Let $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$. Show that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a+1}{\sqrt{a+bc}} \geq \frac{2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$
Let $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$. Show that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a+1}{\sqrt{a+bc}} \geq \frac{2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$
My idea:
By am-gm we get that $bc\leq \frac{1}{27a}$
From here I wrote the inequality we want to solve as $\sum_{cyc} \frac{(a+1)*(\sqrt{27})}{\sqrt{27a^2+1}} \geq \frac{2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$
I observed that 1/3 is at least a double solution and from here I tried doing the linear method, but got to nothing useful...Hope one of you can help me!

It’s just my way, but if the sum of variables are given, I would like to make the given inequality’s LHS and RHS same degree. This allows you to feel free from the given sum condition.(Why? That’s quite intuitive.)

(continued) So, you can continue from here(if you don’t feel bad reseting the problem): $$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {(a+b)+(a+c)}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}} ≥ \dfrac {2(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$.

By Jensen:
$$\sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a+1}{\sqrt{a+bc}}\ge (a+1+b+1+c+1)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{(a+1)(a+bc)+(b+1)(b+ca)+(c+1)(c+ab)}{(a+1)+(b+1)+(c+1)}}}=$$
$$=\dfrac{8}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)+3abc+(ab+bc+ca)}}\ge \dfrac{2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
$$a+b+c=p=1\ ,\ ab+bc+ca=q\le\dfrac{1}{3}\ ,\ abc=r$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 16(1-2q)^2\ge 2-q+3r$$
$$q^2\ge 3r$$
$$2-q+3r\le2-q+q^2\le16(1-2q)^2 \Leftrightarrow \left(q-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\left(q-\dfrac{2}{3}\right)\ge 0$$

My intuition is just as my comment above, and I’d like to give you a full solution.
From my comment above, we can change the problem to:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {(a+b)+(a+c)}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}} ≥ \dfrac {2(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$.
This inequality can be proved easily:
\begin{align}
& (a+b)+(a+c) \geq 2\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}. \\
\therefore \; & \dfrac{(a+b)+(a+c)}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}} \geq 2. \\
\ \\
& \text{ISW, } \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{(a+b)+(a+c)}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}\geq 6. \\
\ \\
& 4(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca) \geq 0. \\
\Rightarrow \; & 6(a^2+b^2+c^2) \geq 2(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca). \\
\Rightarrow \; & 6 \geq \dfrac{2(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}. \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {(a+b)+(a+c)}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}} \geq 6 \geq \dfrac {2(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}.
\end{align}
Edit. I forgot to explain the change:
Firstly, making the same degree can make us ignore the sum condition, since making $(a, b, c) \to (ka, kb, kc)$ doesn’t impact the inequality, which means ignorable.
Also, this was my thought:
$$ \dfrac {a+1}{\sqrt{a+bc}} = \dfrac{a+(a+b+c)}{\sqrt{a(a+b+c)+bc}} = \dfrac{(a+b)+(a+c)}{\sqrt{a^2+ab+ac+bc}} = \dfrac{(a+b)+(a+c)}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}. \\
\dfrac{2}{a^2+b^2+c^2} = \dfrac{2(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}. $$
